# Sigma algebra of stochastic process

Tags: pr.probability, measure-theory, stochastic-processes

A stochastic process is a collection $(X_t)_{t\in T}$ of random variables from a prob. space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ to some measurable space $(E,\mathcal{E})$. Now, in order to understand the whole process as a 'single' random variable one look at it as a map $X:\Omega\to E^T$, where $E^T=\prod_{t\in T}E$ is the set of all functions from $T$ to $E$.

$E^T$ is usually equipped with the product sigma algebra $\mathcal{E}^T$ which is produced by the one-dimensional cylinder sets, i.e. $\mathcal{E}^T=\sigma(\pi^{-^1}(A): A\in\mathcal{E}, t\in T)$ (is is the same as the sigma algebra produced by all finite-dimensional cylinders?), where $\pi_t$ is the projection map from $E^T$ to $E$. Now, if we are interested just in a subspace $S\subset E^T$, then it is often the case that $S\notin\mathcal{E}^T$.

For example take $T=[0,1]$, $E=\mathbb{R}$, $\mathcal{E}=\mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{R}}$ and $C[0,1]$ as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{[0,1]}$, then $C[0,1]\notin\mathcal{E}^T$.

By looking at $\mathcal{S}=S\cap \mathcal{E}^T=\{S\cap A:A\in\mathcal{E}^T\}$ one can avoid this problem. Now my main question: If our subspace $S$ is a metric space it is natural to look at the Borel $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{B}_S$. Is it always the case that $\mathcal{S}=\mathcal{B}_S$? I think that we need some additional property like separability, but I cannot prove it.

Comment: Take $S=E^T$, endowed with the discrete metric.

Comment: And if we assume that $E$ is separable with Borel sigma algebra $\mathcal{B}_E$?

Comment: The question is rather what $S$ should be. It works for $S=C[0,1]$, but there is no reason it should work for every metric space.

Comment: OK, thank you. Does it also work for the space of cadlag functions $D[0,1]$ if it is equipped with a "right" metric?

Comment: I'm not sure. The reason why it works for $C[0,1]$ is that every function in $C[0,1]$ is determined by countably many coordinates. I don't know if this argument transfers to cadlag functions.

Comment: This works for $D[0,1]$ as well, and this is pretty well known. See Theorem 14.5 of Billingsley's "Convergence of Probability Measures."

Comment: I've already found out but thank you. Unfortunately, Billingsley's proof is hard to read and without many details. Do you maybe know some other reference or proof which is "easier" to read?